# How to count black pixels of video frame?

Tags: python, rgb, video-processing

I need to calculate the black pixels in a video. I found python code that reads RGB channels and calculates the average RGB value of the frame. Instead I need it to count the black and colored pixels and calculate the average of just the colored pixels.
This is the program that I've been working on

````
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    b = frame[:, :, :1]
    g = frame[:, :, 1:2]
    r = frame[:, :, 2:]
    # computing the mean
    b_mean = round(np.mean(b))
    g_mean = round(np.mean(g))
    r_mean = round(np.mean(r))


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()```
````

Comment: black is subjective. You could apply a threshold value to each channel and consider black those pixels that have a very low value in all R, G and B channels. You ill need to threshold each channel and then apply an OR operator to them, if the result is still 0 it means all channels are low. Take a look at how to apply thresholds.  Then the remaining pixels are not black and you can apply the average https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html

Comment: Do you have a rule that tells you whether a pixel is "black" or not? Do you know a way to select elements of a Numpy array that meet a condition? Do you know a way to count elements in that selection? If you put those things together, can you solve the problem?

Comment: Note: video do not uses RGB, so if could be much easier, faster, and with less artefacts (due to decompression) if you check original YCC data. Second: "video" is generic. Some video uses 16 as black, some 0.

Answer (score 1):

First of, you should ask yourself *"What do I consider black?"*. Do you want to count pixels that are "perfectly" black (RGB (0, 0, 0), grayscale 0) or pixels that just *appear* black? If the latter is the case, you need to introduce a threshold for what counts as black.

Note: The code you posted lacks the cv2 import :)

One solution to accomplish the task:

```
[...]
# this threshold controls what counts as black (in grayscale)
black_threshold = 0

# convert the image to grayscale
frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# count black pixels
black_pixel_count = len(np.argwhere(frame_gray <= black_threshold))

# count non-black pixels
non_black_pixel_count = (frame_gray.shape[0] * frame_gray.shape[1]) - black_pixel_count

# average for all channels, excluding black pixels
red_avg = int(np.mean(frame[frame_gray > black_threshold][:, 0]))
green_avg = int(np.mean(frame[frame_gray > black_threshold][:, 1]))
blue_avg = int(np.mean(frame[frame_gray > black_threshold][:, 2]))
```

Comment: Then consider accepting the answer above to help other people with a similar problem.